# can't get rid of milliseconds while querying on UNIX time in CouchBase

Tags: couchbase, datetime-format, sql++

I need to get a date from my collection in couchbase in standard datetime format and its formatted in epoch mode. I used millis_to_str() method using all supported date format possible but in the output I still get milliseconds.
I used SPLIT method to get rid of milliseconds but is there any convenient approach to delete milliseconds?

I've tried millis_to_str() to convert epoch time to string with the format of '1111-11-11 11:11:11' but I get the milliseconds too.

> Select MILLIS_TO_STR(1667640877196, "1111-11-11 11:11:11") as pDate
> out:

```
  {
    "pDate": "2022-11-05 13:04:37.196"
  },
```

and I also tried to cast the converted string into utc (str_to_utc).
Millis_to_utc() is not doing any good either.
I had to split the string to get rid of milliseconds:

> SPLIT(MILLIS_TO_STR(creationDate, "1111-11-11 11:11:11"),".")

Is there any method that actually work on UNIX/EPOCH?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Go-style formatting, e.g.

```
SELECT MILLIS_TO_STR(1667640877196, "2006-01-02 15:04:05");
```

(2006 = year, 01 = month, 02 = day, 15 = 24-hour hour, etc.)

Or if you're using 7.1 you can use:

```
SELECT MILLIS_TO_STR(1667640877196, "%D %T");
```

or

```
SELECT MILLIS_TO_STR(1667640877196, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried different formatting but the problem still remains. guess that's solved in 7.1 but I'm using version 7

Comment: fixed format you can use SUBSTR() vs SPLIT() pre 7.1